# Program will compile with no errors, but will not execute. What's wrong? (in C)

Tags: c

So for some reason whenever I try and compile this program in gedit, it will work with no issues (no errors). However when I try and execute it with ./prgram, it just skips to the next line in terminal. I'm not sure if it's the program that just doesn't work, or if it has something to do with my compiler. Thanks! (this is a homework assignment, so bare with the extras as they are necessary for full credit)

```
#include <stdio.h>
const double CEL = 32;
const double KEL = 459.67;

double FahToCel(double);
double FahToKel(double);

int main()
    {
    double cel;
    double kel;
    double faren;
    char i[1] = "a";
    while (i == "a")
    {
        printf("Enter a temperature in farenheit(enter s to stop):\n"); 
        scanf("%lf\n", &faren);
        printf("%lf Farenheit is equal to %lf Celsius, and %lf Kelvin\n", faren, FahToCel(cel), FahToKel(kel));
        if (kel <= -274)
            printf("Atomic motion has stopped\n");
        else if ((kel >= -274) && (kel <= 273))
            printf("Water freezes here\n");
        else if ((kel >= 274) && (kel <= 280))
            printf("You'll need a sweater\n");
        else if ((kel >= 281) && (kel <= 294))
            printf("A bit chilly\n");
        else 
            printf("Ahh, that's better\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

double FahToCel(double faren)
{
    double cel;
    cel = (faren - CEL) * 5/9;
    return cel;
}

double FahToKel(double faren)
{
    double kel;
    kel = (faren + KEL) * 5/9;
    return kel;
}
```

Comment: how are you compiling it? you definitely aren't compiling it in gedit....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Click Here To Run Your Program](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php)

```
#include <stdio.h>
const double CEL = 32;
const double KEL = 459.67;

double FahToCel(double);
double FahToKel(double);
void clean_stdin(void);
int main()
    {
    double cel;
    double kel;
    double faren;
    char i = 'a';
    while (i != 'N')
    {
        printf("\nEnter a temperature in farenheit :\n"); 
        scanf("%lf", &faren);
        printf("%lf Farenheit is equal to %lf Celsius, and %lf Kelvin\n", faren, FahToCel(cel), FahToKel(kel));
        if (kel <= -274)
            printf("Atomic motion has stopped\n");
        else if ((kel >= -274) && (kel <= 273))
            printf("Water freezes here\n");
        else if ((kel >= 274) && (kel <= 280))
            printf("You'll need a sweater\n");
        else if ((kel >= 281) && (kel <= 294))
            printf("A bit chilly\n");
        else 
            printf("Ahh, that's better\n");
        printf("Do you want to Continue ? ( N : Stop) : \n"); 
        clean_stdin();
        scanf("%c",&i);
    }
    return 0;
}

double FahToCel(double faren)
{
    double cel;
    cel = (faren - CEL) * 5/9;
    return cel;
}

double FahToKel(double faren)
{
    double kel;
    kel = (faren + KEL) * 5/9;
    return kel;
}

void clean_stdin(void)
{
    int c;
    do {
        c = getchar();
    } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

Comment: @Val Gocan-Paval , This is Perfect Solution ? Let me know....You should input N to stop that Loop

Comment: Thanks that's perfect! I'll just figure out on my own how to hide the other decimal points.

Answer (score 1):

In your program the condition in `while (i == "a")` does not evaluate to `TRUE`. So it does not go into the while loop and the program does `return 0`  and exits.

To compare strings, you should use `strcmp()`.

Also, `char i[1] = "a";` makes array of chars of length 1, but you want it to be 2 chars long. One for `'a'` and 2nd for `'\0'` to make it as NULL terminated string.

Comment: In the homework assignment, the loop has to stop when the user enters a letter, so I thought that initializing the loop with a letter and than asking the user to input another letter should they wish to cancel the program would work.

Comment: @ValGocan-Paval the point is that in C, the test `i == "a"` does **not** test whether `i` is the string `"a"`

Answer (score 1):

In while Loop Condition u can use...this...

```
 while (i[0] == 'a')
```

So that it will check for single character....

Comment: @Val Gocan-Paval ,  Let me know if its solved....or comment here....I will help to solve your homework assignment

Comment: @Val Gocan-Paval , Can you tell me your Program Definition....So that I can do that

Comment: Write a program that requests the user to enter a
Fahrenheit temperature. The program should read the temperature
as a type double number and pass it as an argument to two functions:
FahToCel() and FahToKel(). These functions should calculate
the Celsius equivalent and the Kelvin equivalent (respectively). Then,
display all three temperatures with a precision of two places to the
right of the decimal. You are free to print within each module or
construct a print function, as you wish. When printing, you need
to identify each value with the temperature scale it represents.

Comment: Use
the Internet to find the conversion formula’s for both Fahrenheit to
Celsius and Fahrenheit to Kelvin.
Your conversion functions should use const to create symbolic
representations of the constants which appear in the conversion formulas.
The main() function should use a loop to allow the user to
enter temperatures repeatedly, stopping when a q or other non numeric
value is entered. Use the fact that scanf() returns the number
of items read, so it will return a 1 if it reads a number, but it won’t
return a 1 if the user enters a q .

Comment: The == operator tests for equality,
so you can use it to compare the return value of scanf() with 1 .
Don’t forget to display prompts to make sure the user enters the
correct temperature before you convert it.
Finally, when you calculate the kelvin temperature, display a commentary
line based upon the computed value.
• less than -274: "Atomic motion stopped"
• -274 to 273: "Water freezes here"
• 274 to 280: "You’ll need a sweater"
• 281 to 294: "A bit chilly"
• 295+: "Ahh, that’s better"